# Live Wallpaper using Min3d Library

Tags: android, 3d, live-wallpaper

I have a 3d object wavefront .obj file, I want to use that .obj file in my live wallpaper application.
can someone give me an idea , how can I use min3D library for Live wallpaper application ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this template https://code.google.com/p/min3d-live-wallpaper-fork/